# Error when opening Terminal

Tags: unix, terminal

The following line appears as soon as I open terminal. What does this mean?

```
-bash: exort: command not found
```

Comment: Yes. Was a minor misspelling as you said in my bash_profile. Used nano on bash_profile to correct the spelling. Thank you.

Comment: Good to read that, ssosina :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be because in your `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`, etc. there is a line saying `exort` instead of `export`.

Look for it in your home directory with:

```
grep "exort" ~/.*
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what `exort` is - perhaps a misspelling of export?  To track down this error, you'll need to examine your login scripts.  You can use a text editor (i.e. `vi`) to view the files in question and search for `exort`.  I recommend looking in the following files, if they exist:

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.profile
/etc/bashrc
/etc/profile
/etc/profile.d/*
```